# Past exam question for a matrices $A$ and $B$.

Tags: linear-algebra

The matrix $A$ row reduces to $B$:
\begin{equation*}
A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 4 \\
0 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 0 \\
2 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 4 \\
3 & 2 & 5 & 4 & 4
\end{bmatrix}, \qquad B = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 & 1 & -4 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation*}

> Which one of the following statements is incorrect?
>
> > 1. The first, second, third and fourth columns of $A$ span $\text{col}(A)$.
> > 2. The first, second, fourth and fifth columns of $A$ span $\text{col}(A)$.
> > 3. The second, third, fourth and fifth columns of $A$ span $\text{col}(A)$.
> > 4. The first, second, third and fourth rows of $A$ span $\text{row}(A)$.
> > 5. The first, second, third and fourth rows of $B$ span $\text{row}(A)$.

Since $B$ is not row reduced all the way how can we deduce what spans (or in this case does not span) $\text{col}(A)$?

> Let $T_A:\mathbb{R}^5\mapsto \mathbb{R}^4$ be the corresponding linear transformation. The kernel of $T_A$ is the set $\left\{v\in \mathbb{R}^5: T_A(v) = 0\right\}$. What is the dimension of the kernel of $T_A$?

The nullspace has one vector $\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
-1 \\
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}$ so the dimension of the kernel is one right?

> Which one the following statements is incorrect?
>   1. For some elementary matrices $E_1,E_2,\ldots,E_n$ we have $A = E_1E_2\ldots E_nB$.
>   2. For some elementary matrices $E_1,E_2,\ldots,E_m$, $F_1,F_2,\ldots,F_n$ we have $E_1E_2\ldots E_mA = F_1F_2\ldots F_nB$.
>   3. For some elementary matrices $E_1,E_2,\ldots,E_n$ we have $E_1E_2\ldots E_nA = \begin{bmatrix}
> 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
> \end{bmatrix}$.
>   4. For some elementary matrices $E_1,E_2,\ldots,E_n$ we have $E_1E_2\ldots E_nA = I_5$.
>   5. For some elementary matrices $E_1,E_2,\ldots,E_n$ we have $E_1E_2\ldots E_nA = B$.

Not sure how to do this one. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It would be better to ask this as two separate questions since both are fairly long.

Comment: For the first one, $B$ is in row echelon form.  So, even though it isn't in reduced row echelon form, the pivot locations are the same and can be identified.

Comment: Okay so the solution is (b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, the answer is 1, as in the columns of $A$ are **not** spanned by the first four columns. The reason for this lies in the third column of $B$: because the column contains no pivots, the third column of $A$ lies in the span of the previous two columns (indeed, it is the sum of the previous two columns, as you can verify). Therefore, the first four columns are linearly dependent, and hence cannot span the full four-dimensional columnspace.

Don't worry about the fact that $B$ is not completely in reduced row-echelon form. It is in row-echelon form (according to some definitions), and can be turned into row-echelon form according to other definitions by dividing the bottom row by $4$. Either way, it is clear in which columns the pivots lie.

The nullspace of $T_A$ is *spanned* by the given vector, yes. It does not have one vector in it, as the nullspace contains every multiple of this vector, e.g. $(2, 2, -2, 0, 0)$, as well. But yes, because this single vector is spanning, and non-zero hence linearly independent, it forms a basis for $\operatorname{null} T_A$, proving the dimension is $1$.

Alternatively, you could use the rank-nullity theorem, or simply count the number of columns in $B$ without pivots.

For the final question, the answer can quickly be seen to be 4, simply because $I_5$ is a $5 \times 5$ matrix, and elementary matrices are all square, so $E_1 E_2 \ldots E_n A$ must be a $4 \times 5$ matrix like $A$.